# Include Wordpress' jQuery UI to my plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I have created a wordpress plugin and I am trying to upload it to wordpress.org. My problem is that the community does not allow me to load jQuery UI from jQuery UI site or locally. They only accept to use Wordpress' jQuery UI. I am trying to use this code to do it but datepicker does not work:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
```

It is strange, because when I load jQuery UI locally datepicker works fine.

Anybody understands what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code for add script file for wordpress plugin

```
function my_admin_init() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');//enables UI
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker', $pluginfolder . '/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core') );
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery.ui.theme', '/wp-content/themes/<themename>/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css');
    }
    add_action('admin_init', 'my_admin_init');
```

but make sure to include the css file and all the associated images (like any jQuery UI instalation).

Comment: The problem is that jQuery UI is not being loaded with wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');. And datepicker is included in Wordpress and they don't want me to use an external file. They want me to use Wordpress' jQuery UI datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

For wp-admin:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_backend_scripts' );
```

For Fron End:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_frontend_scripts' );
```

Note: my_backend_scripts & my_frontend_scripts are the functions to enque your scripts and styles.

e.g.

```
function my_frontend_scripts() {



            wp_enqueue_script(
                'he-scripts',
                plugins_url('js/scripts.js', dirname(__FILE__)),
                array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-slider' )
            );

            wp_register_style('he-ex', plugins_url('css/style.css', dirname(__FILE__)));        

            wp_enqueue_style( 'he-ex' );    


    }
```